# ng-keyup doesn't do function

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how ng-keyup works and I found some tutorials and sources, but when I tried to make one myself it doesn't work. You can see my codepen example here, http://codepen.io/alucardu/pen/XbOWRP and this is a JSfiddle example I tried to recreate http://jsfiddle.net/r74a5m25/.

html

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="exampleCtrl">
    <input ng-model="test" ng-keyup="search()" />
    <br/>
    <span>{{test}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
function exampleCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.search = function() {
    alert('test');
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem come from the version of your angular. The earliest doc I can find in angularjs about `ng-keyup` is on the version [1.1.2](https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/docs/api/ng.directive:ngKeyup). And you are using the previous version, 1.1.1.

Personnaly, I try with 1.2.0 in your [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpJKrR) and it works
: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js

This version is use in the JSFiddle that's why it works fine there.

Comment: I'm glad if it's help.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use `ng-keyup` in the example. You have to bind your function to your input, just like you do with `ng-model`:

`<input ng-model="test" ng-keyup="search()"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to try down with latest version of angularjs. The formats should be maintained.

```
 <div ng-app="testApp">
      <div ng-controller="exampleCtrl">
        <input ng-model="test" ng-keyup="search()" />
        <br/>
        <span>{{test}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
myApp = angular.module("testApp",[]);
myApp.controller("exampleCtrl",function($scope){

  $scope.search=function(){
    alert("test");
  }

});
```